# Logistic regression vs MLE of conditional probability

Tags: regression, logistic, conditional-probability

I am trying to build a classification model from a large dataset (50M instances) with a  categorical independent variable (`pred`) and a binary dependent variable (`class`). The dependent variable is very skewed - only 2K positive instances. What confuses me is the  very low predicted probability of logistic regression model.

`(glm(class~pred,family=binomal)),`
compared to standard conditional probability estimate

```
(prop.table(table(class,pred),2)[2,]):


           1            2            3            4            5            6      ...
7.898106e-03 5.133151e-03 3.332895e-03 2.162637e-03 1.402706e-03 9.095645e-04 (glm)...
1.029593e-01 1.572959e-02 4.906542e-03 1.695033e-03 7.622454e-04 5.922985e-04 (mle)...
```

Is this expected differences? Should I use some method other than logistic regression (results are similar with non-parametric locfit)? Is it OK to report conditional probabilities only?

Comment: I don't see how the logistic regression estimates are "very low" compared to the standard: for item 1 and 2, it's significantly lower (.0079 vs .1 and .005 vs .016), but for 3 through 6 it's about the same or higher.

Comment: @Dougal Thank you for your comment. Differences between MLE and log. regression are (rounded): 0.0951  0.0106  0.0016 -0.0005 -0.0006 -0.0003 -0.0002 -0.0001 -0.0001  (0 for rest 12 points). Total sum for MLE is 0.1279 and for l.r. 0.0225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very vague problem description, but I'm willing to bet the reason why the conditional probability and the logistic regression model give such different predictions is because you haven't coded `pred` as a factor. Instead, continuous values of `pred` impose a grouped linear structure on the linear predictor $\eta = \mbox{logit}(\mbox{Pr}(\mbox{Class}|\mbox{Cred}))$. I don't see any evidence that `pred` is coded as a factor in your data, hence if it takes on numeric values (1, 2, ..., 6), R will treat these as continuous values and base logistic regression predictions under the assumption of a continuous odds ratio comparing subsequent levels of `pred`. As a result, your fitted probabilities must conform to the S-shaped logistic function when plotting predicted probabilities against levels of `pred`.

If you want to get the exact same values as your conditional probability, change your model syntax to:

`fit <- glm(class ~ factor(pred), family=glm)`

And you'll see that the predicted probabilities

```
predict(fit, newdata=data.frame('factor(pred)'=factor(1:6)))
```

Will match the conditional ones perfectly.

Comment: This is correct - thank you very much for correcting my beginner's mistake. David